# How to replace buffer with a search range selection?

Tags: search, buffers, replace

I'd like to replace the entire buffer (file) with the current search range selection:

```
:/pattern1/;,/pattern2/p
```

How this can be achieved?

Comment: Do you mean `:/pat1/;/pat2/d | %d_ | put | 1d`, or do you mean reusing the previous range (which can't be done aside from using the history, AFAIK)?

Comment: @Antony: Yes, I mean the 1st example of yours. Removing everything else apart of the content of current search range. If you could post it as the answer, would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to delete the range you are interested in, delete the remainder of the buffer into the black hole register, then put the text you want to keep into the empty buffer:

```
:/pat1/;/pat2/d | %d_ | put | 1d
```

The final `1d` is to tidy up the empty line at the top, and handily leaves
the cursor at the start of the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a straightforward solution, but a possible workaround is the following. Consider that you have the following buffer and you want to keep the lines `dolor` to `amet`:

```
Lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
consectetur
adipiscing
elit
```

First, mark the lines you want to keep:

```
:/pattern1/,/pattern2/norm! AXXX
```

Here that would be `/dolor/,/amet/norm! AXXX` and you would get:

```
Lorem
ipsum
dolorXXX
sitXXX
ametXXX
consectetur
adipiscing
elit
```

Delete the lines which wasn't marked:

```
:g!/XXX/d
```

You would get:

```
dolorXXX
sitXXX
ametXXX
```

Now you have only the lines you wanted, remove the marks:

```
:%s/XXX$//
```

You'll get:

```
dolor
sit
amet
```

---

Of course it is possible to wrap that into a function:

```
function! RemoveOtherLines(pattern1, pattern2)
    execute '/' . a:pattern1 . '/,/' . a:pattern2 . '/norm! AXXX'
    execute 'g!/XXX/d'
    execute '%s/XXX$//'
endfunction
```

But maybe you'll get some problems with some escaped patterns.